What is the data controller/processor relationship in making a phone call?
Last year I asked this question regarding specifically making a Subject Access Request of a phone company.  After (rather slowly) thinking about it it seems the question is rather wider.
Take a telephone call between Alice and Bob who do not share a phone company.  There are two bits of personal data that all entities must process for that to happen, their respective telephone numbers.  Alice/Bob may or may not be data controllers, mostly depending on if this is their work or personal phone.  For the purposes of this question take the instance that Alice is an private individual and Bob is working for a company, perhaps the suspected scammer in the above question, with the call initiated by Bob.  I think their respective phone companies are data controllers of their own personal data, as specified in their phone contract.
What about the non-respective phone companies, eg.  Bob's phone company for Alice's phone number?  Is Bob's phone company a data controller for this data, with all the responsibilities that go with that?  Is Bob's phone company a data processor for this data?  If so, for whom?  Is there an exception for such routing type of data processing?

"routing" or "routine"?

@phoog I meant "Routing is the process of selecting a path for traffic in a network"

I assume that processing of telephone numbers for the purpose of routing telephone calls is covered by the "legitimate interest" basis  as well as various legal requirements for record retention (at least), and that therefore no exception is required.

Data controller is whoever "determines the purposes and means of the processing", but telecom is a highly regulated industry with limited latitude to make such decisions. Telecom-specific legislation will also supersede general GDPR rules. For the purpose of this question, it may be necessary to focus on a niche where the telecom provider is actually allowed to determine processing purposes, e.g. data processing that is necessary for billing.


What about the non-respective phone companies, eg. Bob's phone company for Alice's phone number? Is Bob's phone company a data controller for this data, with all the responsibilities that go with that?

Bob's phone company is a data controller for Alice's personal data because it has records that contain her phone number.

Is Bob's phone company a data processor for this data?

No, because it is a data controller for that data.

Is there an exception for such routing type of data processing?

No.
Some may say "but they have the data without Alice's consent!"  The response to that, as always, is that consent is only one lawful basis for processing.  Others that may apply here are compliance with a legal obligation and the legitimate interests of the controller.  In the latter case, in particular, it needs to process Alice's phone number in order to route the call to her phone.
There is no processor-controller relationship between either phone company and Bob's employer.  There is (presumably) a contract for the provision of communications services between Bob's employer and its phone company.  That is not the same as a contract for data processing.  The phone company isn't processing the data on Bob's employer's behalf but rather in connection with providing a service to Bob's  employer.

Reason for processing here: legal requirement. The law mandates the phone company to hold a record for accounting purposes.

@Trish maybe, maybe not.  Among other things, we don't know when the call occured and whether the law requires record retention.  In any event there can be more than one basis for processing.

This answer would be perfect if it addressed the responsibilities it implies DIDWW Ireland Limited have in relation to the linked question, particularly in regards to Article 14 and 15, and the identity of Bob in the presence of an SAR. There is never any question about the justification of processing, but what information is required to be available to Alice upon request.

@User65535 I've added a paragraph.  I understand that the basis for processing isn't part of the question, but I included that part of the answer because this site is flooded with questions assuming that consent is required in every case.  I wanted to forestall that line of discussion.

Under Art 14 of the UK gdpr if DIDWW are data controllers for Alice's telephone number then they must provide Alice with at a minimum their contact details (14.1 a-b).  They must also say "the recipients or categories of recipients of the personal data" (14.1 e), which could include who Bob is, which is the primary objective.

Assuming DIDWW is Bob's employer's phone company, they received Alice's personal data from Bob's employer, not the other way around.  If Alice wants to find out whose phone number originated the call, she should call the number.  If that doesn't work, a subject access request isn't going to help; at best it will show that there was a call from a certain number to her number at a certain time, which she already knows.

@phoog The EU required telecom record retention for law enforcement purposes under the 2006 Data Retention Directive. This was annulled in 2016 by a CJEU ruling which did say that data retention under specific conditions is legal. Currently, this is controlled by a patchwork of national laws.
